# Entity framework doesnt create my tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Im using entity framework code-first in order to set up a database. This is my 2 classes i'd like to use as tables:

```
namespace NinjaNooking.Models
{


    public class Frisorer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Scheman> Schema {get;set;}
    }

    public class Scheman
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Schemat { get; set; }
        public virtual Frisorer frisorer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my context class:

```
namespace NinjaNooking.Models
{

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
       public NameOfMyChoice?()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
        public DbSet<Frisorer> Frisorer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Scheman> Scheman {get;set; }

    }
}
```

I was hoping that this would generate 2 tables in a database for me to acess with ssms,
 im using MVC and if I run the program a database gets created but my tables are not.

Connection string:

```
add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication3-20140312082008;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication3-20140312082008.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: You can find connection string in web config file under . where you are able to edit urs connection with your local database.. please look for Connection String and add that in the question @user

Comment: Its added at the bottom of the question. Thanks

Comment: Document connection string  properly.. the problem i can see is the "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;  . please i will tell which is needed to replaced with it.. I also faces the same problem while doing this

Comment: Look at my editted answer

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Connection String with following
it greatly works for me

```
add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication3-20140312082008;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication3-20140312082008.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thank You! I'll look into that tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually running a query against the context? It may not create them until a query is run.

Also try renaming the variable `Schema`

Comment: Please, have a looka t my edit. Will that work as an connection-string?
Yes, before I created a contreoller that would send the schema property to a view.

Comment: Drop the AttachDBFilename for now